# Ошибка при создании цикла for

Tags: ios, swift

попытка создать цикл for в swift приводит к двум ошибкам:

> expected '{' to start the body of for-each loop
>
> Braced block of statements is an unused closure

код для воспроизведения:

```
for i in 0..< numberOfEuropeCities {

}
```

Comment: давайте что ли переоткроем. вопрос вполне себе имеет место - у swift есть некоторые странности с syntax enforcing. я думаю, может такой вопрос пригодиться.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, сначала вопрос надо привести к нормальному виду. сейчас вопрос, по-моему, бесполезен для тех, кто столкнётся с аналогичной проблемой: они ведь его просто не найдут поисковиками. потому я и голосовал за закрытие.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin попробовал исправить

Answer (score 2):

пробела там либо не должно быть

```
for i in 0..<numberOfEuropeCities {
```

либо быть с обеих сторон

```
for i in 0 ..< numberOfEuropeCities {
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!
У меня ошибка пропала, когда добавил пробел:

```
for i in 0 ..< numberOfEuropeCities
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, Вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтете полезными. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/82851)

Comment: @totorro пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее! Это не фраза "спасибо", это авторское решение (вполне нормальная практика)!

Comment: @PavelMayorov отличие в пробеле между нулём и точками?

Comment: @NickVolynkin с этим языком не знаком - но, судя по ответу, да